# Stuck up in my Multiplication table in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Heres my code:

```
   <body >
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        document.write("Multiplication Table </br> </br>")
        var num = parseInt(prompt(" Enter a number:"));
        var a;

        document.write("<table border = '1' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0>' ")
        for(a=1;a<=10;a++){
            {
            document.write("<tr><td>"+ num + "x" + a + "=" + a * num + "<tr><td>");
            }
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    </script>
</body>
```

This should be the sample output:

[image]

Comment: And? What's your question?

Comment: my question is on the image I posted:

Comment: problem is there is 2 input example: input 1: 3; input 2: 5 then it will show a table from 3x1-10 4x1-10 5x1-10

Comment: Did you neet to take two inputs and get the tables from input 1 to input 2?

Comment: thank you so much.. I'm still learning JS. its a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Need to read to numbers and cycle throw them, also corrected the close of `td` and `tr`

```js
        document.write("Multiplication Table </br> </br>")
        var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Input 1:"));
        var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Input 2:"));
        var a;
for(num=num1;num<=num2;num++){
        document.write("<table border = '0' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' style='display:inline; margin:5px' >")
        for(a=1;a<=10;a++){
            {
            document.write("<tr><td style='border:solid black 1px;'>"+ num + "x" + a + "=" + a * num + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
        document.write("</table>");
}
```